# Drilldown bar charts using MDX parameter expressions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

I have two barcharts , chart1is representing  for year, sales amount .Year is on x axis and amount on y axis . I have created the chart with year parameter . 
Created the another report with year , quarter, sales amount . Quarter on x axis and sales amount on y axis .
Now I added year parameter to chart2.
Now in chart1 , at action tab mapped to chart2 wrt to bar in chart 1 and added year parameter , so that when I will click on bar it will redirect to chart2 and display quarter barchart as per chart1 .
When I was clicked on chart1 bar it is getting redirected with blank parameter value .
Can any body suggest how to resolve the issue or any example on MDX parameter drilldown charts .

Answer (score 0):

MDX values look something like "[Date].[Year].&[2015]" and this is what you need to replicate as the parameter value for the action. You should be able to determine your cube's exact key syntax by expanding the dimension in the query designer or by creating a "new MDX query" in SSMS and dragging out a single member from the cube browser to the query designer surface.

Once you have the syntax, it's just a matter of creating that string through an SSRS expression on the click action:

Example: ="[Date].[Year].&[" & Fields!Year.Value & "]"

Comment: Thank you Daniel can you pls suggest some video tutorial ... That will be more helpful.